# Creating separate google-services.json files for Preview and Production environments in an Expo project and resolving eas build error

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing an application using Expo. The application is registered on the Google Play Console, and currently, I have two different environments, Preview and Production. I need to create separate google-services.json files and set them up correctly for each of these environments. Also I use react-native-map but not firebase stuff.

Is there a recommended way to create and manage different google-services.json files for Preview and Production environments? Also, I would appreciate guidance on how to utilize these files in my Expo project and how to set them up on the Google Play Console.

Additionally, when I run the command eas build -e preview -p android --local, I encounter the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[RUN_GRADLEW] * What went wrong:
[RUN_GRADLEW] Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
[RUN_GRADLEW] > Malformed root json
```

app.config.js

```
import 'dotenv/config'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
const IS_DEV = process.env.APP_VARIANT === 'development'
const IS_PREVIEW = process.env.APP_VARIANT === 'preview'

export default {
  expo: {
    name: IS_PREVIEW ? 'a Dev' : 'a',
    slug: 'a',
    scheme: 'a',
    version: '1.0.1',
    orientation: 'portrait',
    icon: './assets/splash.png',
    userInterfaceStyle: 'light',
    runtimeVersion: {
      policy: 'sdkVersion'
    },
    splash: {
      image: './assets/splash.png',
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: [
      '**/*'
    ],
    extra: {
      eas: {
        projectId: ''
      }
    },
    owner: 'a',
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: true,
      // jsEngine: 'jsc',
      bundleIdentifier: IS_PREVIEW ? 'a.dev' : 'a',
      associatedDomains: ['applinks:a.dev'],
      buildNumber: dayjs().format('YYYYMMDDHHmm')
    },
    android: {
      package: IS_PREVIEW ? 'a.dev' : 'a',
      // jsEngine: 'jsc',
      googleServicesFile: IS_PREVIEW ? './google-services-dev.json' : './google-services.json',
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: './assets/splash.png',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
      },
      config: {
        googleMaps: {
          apiKey: IS_PREVIEW ? 'a' : 'b'
        }
      },
      intentFilters: [
        {
          action: 'VIEW',
          autoVerify: true,
          data: [
            {
              scheme: 'https',
              host: 'a.dev',
              pathPrefix: '/a'
            }
          ],
          category: ['BROWSABLE', 'DEFAULT']
        }
      ]
    },
    web: {
      favicon: './assets/favicon.png'
    },
    plugins: [
      [
        '@stripe/stripe-react-native',
        {
          merchantIdentifier: '',
          enableGooglePay: false
        }
      ]
    ],
    updates: {
      url: 'https://a'
    },
    jsEngine: 'hermes'
  }
}
```

If there are any solutions or information related to this error, I would appreciate it if you could share that as well.

I also have a feeling that creating a new project on the Google Play Console might be the only way to resolve this issue, but I would like to know if there are any other methods.

Thank you for your assistance.